# What is a math problem that is proven to not be expressable analytically/algebraically and what is that proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

There is an intuitive feeling the one may encounter, that is: "All math problems can be expressed analytically, and solved algebraically"

Some problems may be harder to be expressed analytically ( i can imagine graph problems, for instance, harder to express anatically than say geometric problems).

But is there a problem that is proven to be impossible to express analytically, and what is that proof?

This question is NOT about problems that are proven to not be solvable as the first answer is trying to answer, it is about problems that are proven to impossible to express in an algebratic/analytic form

I am asking because I don't want my sense of problem-solving to be based on bare feeling and intuition but based on proof seeking ( i can imagine how the famous mathematician `Srinivasa Ramanujan` may disagree in this part as he is the father of intuitive approach in math src: https://www.bbvaopenmind.com/en/science/leading-figures/ramanujan-the-man-who-saw-the-number-pi-in-dreams/ )

(Execuse my off-topic tags as i am taging fields that i expect to contain such non-anatical problems)

Comment: [Abel-Ruffini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem): there is no general formula for the solutions to a polynomial equation of degree $\ge 5$.

Comment: it is indeed , but that's a problem that can be expressed anatically but cannot be solved anatically , the question is about a problem that is proven to be impossible to express anatically ?

Comment: So... you are asking for an explicit example of a question that cannot be posed?

Answer (score 3):

There are many mathematical problems that have been proved not to be solvable, given a precise definition of *solvable*. Here are a few:

- [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)
- [Solving general polynomial equations using radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)
- [Doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube) with rule and compass
- [Trisecting angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) with rule and compass
- [Squaring the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle)  with rule and compass
- [Integrating $e^{x^2}$ in elementary terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_impossibility

Comment: I'd say that integrating $e^{x^2}$ and finding a closed-form solution is the most common one that people learn of during their calculus studies.

Comment: Sorry the question is not about problems that are proven to not be solvable , it is about problems that are proven not be impossible to solve using the analytical approach

Comment: @The Pointer I don't understand what you mean by "closed form solution" for the integration of $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70850

Comment: @The pointer I don't see the connection between the reference you give and the closed dorm solution of $e^{x^2}$...

Comment: @lhf can't you see how the answer you have given does'nt have anything to do with the actuall question

Comment: @JeanMarie "*In mathematics, an expression is said to be a closed-form expression if it can be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of certain "well-known" functions. Typically, these well-known functions are defined to be elementary functions—constants, one variable $x$, elementary operations of arithmetic ($+ - \times \div$), nth roots, exponent and logarithm (which thus also include trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions).*" The integral of $e^{x^2}$ cannot be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of elementary functions, right?

Comment: @The Pointer I had misunderstood your first remark as "the antiderivative of $e^{x^2}$ **can have** such a closed form" (read it again...).

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, no. I meant that, with regards to integration, this concept is usually *introduced* as an *attempt* to integrate $e^{x^2}$ and find a closed-form solution, and when the student realises (through their attempts) or are told that they cannot integrate such an expression, *then* the concept of not all antiderivatives having a closed-form solution is introduced to them. So it is typically *introduced* as finding a closed-form solution for the integration of $e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I (sort of) know of, to what I *think* you are saying, is an attempt to give *concrete* examples in certain set theory or measure theory contexts where existence of an example is proven using Axiom of Choice/Zorn's Lemma. For example: a concrete example of a non-(Lebesgue)-measurable subset of real numbers. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set .

Another example are computable numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number . We know that there are countably many, which means that almost all real numbers are not computable, but it is impossible (in principle) to give a concrete example of a non-computable number. (See however https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence .)